# Gulp-octo is ignoring my choice of output directory

Tags: gulp, octopus-deploy

I'm trying to build an Octopus Deploy package for an angular-cli project using Gulp and [Gulp-Octo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@octopusdeploy/gulp-octo):

```
const gulp = require("gulp"),
    octopus = require("@octopusdeploy/gulp-octo"),
    version = require("./package.json").version;

gulp.task("octopack",
    ["build-prod"],
    () => gulp.src("dist/*")
        .pipe(octopus.pack(
            "zip", // octopackjs does not support nupkg format yet
            {
                id: "myprojectid",
                version: `${version}.${commandLineOptions.buildnumber}`
            }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./octopus'))
);
```

This creates a package with the correct contents and version number, but *it always goes into the current directory (alongside `gulpfile.js`) instead of the directory that I specified in `gulp.dest()`.*

I have tried all of the following variations in the call to `gulp.dest`, with the same result:

- `./octopus`
- `./octopus/`
- `octopus/`
- `octopus`
- `path.join(__dirname, 'octopus')`

**Am I misunderstanding how `gulp.dest()` works, or is `octopus.pack()` doing something weird?**

(Note: If I leave out the `gulp.dest()` altogether then no zip file is created.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in `gulp-octo`. In [this line](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/gulp-octo/blob/e08abdd/lib/pack.js#L31) they set the path of the generated archive. Unfortunately they just use the filename of the archive instead of a full path (which is [what they're supposed to do](https://github.com/gulpjs/vinyl#optionspath)), so the file is always written relative to the current working directory.

I might send them a pull request when I get the chance, since this is an easy fix.

In the meantime you can use the following workaround:

```
var path = require('path');

gulp.task("default",
    () => gulp.src("dist/*")
        .pipe(octopus.pack(
            "zip", // octopackjs does not support nupkg format yet
            {
                id: "myprojectid",
                version: `${version}.${commandLineOptions.buildnumber}`
            }))
        .on('data', (f) => { f.path = path.join(f.base, f.path) })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./octopus'))
);
```